# How to collect performance trace via CDP commands through Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to collect Chrome Profiler trace dump via Selenium - Python similar to [this approach in JAVA](https://zchandikaz.medium.com/start-chrome-profile-recording-from-selenium-java-a2fee0351396)

Appropriate [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Tracing/) commands are -

```
Tracing.start
Tracing.end
Tracing.dataCollected
```

I saw some examples of [BiDi Api](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/bidi_api/) and tried using them but unable to replicate my use case in Python.

Please help with an example of listening to `Tracing.dataCollected` event asynchronously and collecting Trace dump via Selenium-Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those performance logs for Python / Selenium using SeleniumBase:
https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase - (`pip install seleniumbase`)

Here's an example that gets the performance logs while bypassing a CAPTCHA:

```py
from rich.pretty import pprint
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True, log_cdp=True)
try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://seleniumbase.io/apps/turnstile")
    driver.uc_switch_to_frame("iframe")
    driver.uc_click("span.mark")
    driver.sleep(3)
    pprint(driver.get_log("performance"))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: These logs are available in Selenium library itself. But I am facing one problem in this approach. I want to extract performance trace for a specfic time period within the test. I marked a specific point of time in my test as current time, Now when I try to extract logs before this timestamp, I do not see any logs. I wanted to compare something before and after this timestamp. I am not sure, if the timestamp mentioned in these log entries are linear

Comment: Those logs include a `"timestamp"` so that you can confirm when the data was generated. You may need to save logs before generating new ones if you're refreshing a page.

Comment: For this approach, If I do driver.get_log once in my test code to extract the last timestamp, it somehow clears the logs entirely. I am unable to fetch performance logs anytime later in the code if I call driver.get_log again. Any idea why this might be so?

Comment: `driver.get_log()` clears the logs after it gets those, so be sure to save any data you record.

Comment: I get it, but it should clear the logs until that point right? If i perform some action and then again call driver.get_log() after some delay, I get no performance logs. There are some Network logs present, but not Tracing.dataCollected event

Comment: Some details here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chromium/selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver.html There's also `driver.get_log('browser')`, `driver.get_log('driver')`, `driver.get_log('client')` and `driver.get_log('server')`.